# How can i call two methods asynchronously?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, asynchronous

I have the following two methods:

```
private static void webservicecalls()
{
   WebServiceOne();
   WebServiceTwo();
}
```

So how i can call these two methods asynchronously instead of waiting for the first web service call to be complete before calling the second web service?

**Update:**

Now both WebSericeOne and WebServiceTwo have sub calls such as:

```
private static void WebServiceOne()
{
    CallOne();
    CallThree();
}

private static void WebServiceTwo()
{
    CallTwo();
    CallFour();
}
```

so i need the call to have the following sequence for the sub calls :-

```
CallOne();
CallTwo();
CallThree();
CallFour();
```

Comment: Does application has User Interface? if so - WinForms, WPF, Silverlight, ASP.NET? Which version of .NET?

Comment: How does operation contract look like? (If this is WCF services calls)

Comment: Re your edit: must the order be **exactly** one/two/three/four? or is it simply that one must come before three, and two must come before four? It matters.

Comment: yes it must be one , two , three, four..

Answer (score 5):

Depending on what are you using to implement `webserviceone` `webservicetwo`, it is quite likely that the web-service tooling itself will have full async support, so the first thing to do is: check that, and use the async API rather than the sync API.

If, for some reason, that does not exist - you could do something like:

```
var task = new Task(() => webservice1());
task.Start();
webservice2();
task.Wait();
```

(obviously you could run both fully async; I'm assuming in the above you just want to run them both in parallel, and "join" at the end)

Re your edit: if the order must be exactly "one","two","three","four", then you can't do them in parallel, so you would have to instead just run the entire thing in the background:

```
new Task(() => {
    webservice1();
    webservice2();
}).Start();
```

which will guarantee the execution order, sacrificing parallelism.

Comment: i tried running the entire thing in the background as you mentioend but it will not run in the intended sequence ..

Comment: @testtest the second version **does** run the intended sequence. It does not do anything different to your original code. If that doesn't work correctly, then your original code is broken.

Answer (score 2):

```
Action one = () => WebServiceOne();
Action two = () => WebServiceTwo();
one.BeginInvoke(null, null);
two.BeginInvoke(null, null);
```

Comment: @MarcGravell: Indeed. Was writing by memory. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I like using an Action.

```
private static void WebServiceCalls()
{ 
    var someState = 3;
    Action a1 = () => { WebserviceOne(); };
    Action a2 = () => { WebserviceTwo(); };

    a1.BeginInvoke(WebServiceCallBack, someState); //see code section below
    a2.BeginInvoke(null, null); //fire and forget...

}
```

This also allows you to create a Callback for handling code:

```
void WebServiceCallBack(IAsyncResult result)
{
    int state = (int)result.AsyncState;
    //do more??
}
```

@Mark brings up a valid point:  If you are working with a webservice within Visual studio, you can use the service reference configuration window to create the Channel Proxy class with async syntax.  (I.e. with the `BeginWebServiceOne` and `EndWebServiceOne` which would preclude the need to create Async wrappers.)

Comment: but this will not control the order of execution inside these methods,, see mu update.. best regards

Comment: @testtest indeed, when you are talking about async, the first thing you usually abandon is control over order of execution

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the task library here, and the navigation for the sub categories on the left

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx